# How to insert a row based on a record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table where 'ID' is an auto number. There are a few records present with the same OrderID. I want to add another record to this table with the same OrderID. I tried the following but it does not do anything.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Orders WHERE OrderID='2344567')
Insert into orders (Product_Id, Quantity, Description, Price)
Values ('" & Product_Id & "', '" & Quantity & "', '" & Description & "', '" & Price & "')
```

Can you help please?

Comment: That code looks like it's come from an application layer and is open to SQL injection attacks; Unless you *really* want to insert the **literal string** `'" & Product_Id & "'` into the column `Product_Id` but I doubt that. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: This is just a sample query, don't worry about injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use

> SET IDENTITY INSERT - Allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column of a table.

In this case you turn on and off the possibility to insert into an identity column which is defined as a sequence

The following link will help to resolve the task: [SQL Server set identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I am using this SQL statement in a vb script. How this works there?

Comment: @bob24 The same as any other query. Prepend and append the appropriate `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` commands to your `INSERT` query, and it'll work as per Marc's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SQL Server Profiler` to see what query will be run on your Db. I think you may have some problems on setting parameters on your application, then you can see what really happening in your Db.

-- If (OrderID='2344567') record is **EXISTS**, your **INSERT** statement doesn't work